# How to Insert Call to Already Imported Function in amd64 Windows DLL using IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, patching, amd64

I am trying to patch a function in 64-bit Windows DLL to load data I have inserted into the resource table of the DLL. I want to insert code something like this:

```
mov     r8d, 0Ah        ; lpType
mov     edx, 0h         ; lpName
xor     ecx, ecx        ; hModule
call    cs:FindResourceW
mov     [rsp+148h+var_B8], rax   ; using existing var_B8 to store hResInfo
mov     rdx, [rsp+148h+var_B8] ; hResInfo
xor     ecx, ecx        ; hModule
call    cs:LoadResource
mov     [rsp+148h+var_B0], rax ; using existing var_B0 to store hResData
mov     rcx, [rsp+148h+var_B0] ; hResData
call    cs:LockResource
; data is now in location referenced by RAX register
```

The first problem seems to be the "Assemble" function in IDA pro doesn't handle 64-bit operands, so instructions such as mov r8d, 0Ah I have to assemble by hand and patch via bytes.

However I am not sure how to easily generate the call cs:FindResourceW instruction. While the "assembly" feature generates code the disassembly shows it as gibberish, call instruction "assembled" at 00000272D0B83B4C:

```
.text:00000272D0B83B3F                 mov     r8d, 0Ah
.text:00000272D0B83B45                 mov     edx, 0
.text:00000272D0B83B4A                 xor     ecx, ecx
.text:00000272D0B83B4A ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00000272D0B83B4C                 db  9Ah ; š
.text:00000272D0B83B4D                 db  40h ; @
.text:00000272D0B83B4E                 db  94h ; ”
.text:00000272D0B83B4F                 db 0BDh ; ½
.text:00000272D0B83B50                 db 0D0h ; Ð
.text:00000272D0B83B51                 db    6
.text:00000272D0B83B52                 db    0
.text:00000272D0B83B53                 db  89h ; ‰
.text:00000272D0B83B54                 db  84h ; „
.text:00000272D0B83B55 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00000272D0B83B55                 and     al, 89h
.text:00000272D0B83B55 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00000272D0B83B57                 db  45h ; E
.text:00000272D0B83B58                 db    8
```

To currently assembly I am taking location from import table:

```
.idata:00000272D0BD9440 ; HRSRC __stdcall FindResourceW(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR lpName, LPCWSTR lpType)
.idata:00000272D0BD9440                 extrn FindResourceW:qword
```

Subtracting location where I will insert my code, and subtract 6.

```
  272D0B83B4A (Code location)
 -272D0BD9440 (Import table location)
 -6
===========
00 05 58 F0
```

I am then patching with FF 15 followed by the result in reverse order such as inserting bytes:

```
FF 15 F0 58 05 00
```

This works but is time consuming, is there any better patching option for inserting call instructions quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keypatch](http://www.keystone-engine.org/keypatch/) is a plugin for IDA that uses keystone to assemble instructions for patching. It works much better than IDA's old built-in assembler, and it should be able to handle 64-bit operands.

Comment: This is perfect but I’ll have to port it to IDA 7 SDK as they seem to only support 6 still. However still should be easier than compiling by hand...

Comment: The website says only up to 6.95, but the github repo includes 7.0 https://github.com/keystone-engine/keypatch fwiw, it works fine for me on 7.2